# Prestashop breadcrump header doubled on custom theme

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using a custom Theme for Prestashop and after some updates the navigation breadcrumb header on every page is doubled.

Looks easy but I cannot find the place where it's defined. Is it rather the theme code or prestashop itself?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If your shop is 1.7, the breadcrumb is normally loaded in `YourTheme/templates/layout/layout-both-columns.tpl`

You should find this code:

```
{block name='breadcrumb'}
{include file='_partials/breadcrumb.tpl'}
{/Block}
```

Check that it is not duplicated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have found this reference 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/319440-breadcrumb-declaration-in-prestashop-16/

and based on this, completely removed inclusion of breadcrumb.tpl from header.tpl of my custom theme. Now only one appears.